# Missing Qt-Platform-Plugin "wayland" - pySide / pyQt / visualization

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside, qtwayland, pythonocc

I'm getting started with pythonOCC for my thesis and I'm already struggling at the installation-part.

I managed to install pythonOCC (7.7.0) inside a venv with python 3.9 via Anaconda (took me longer than I want to admit...) on my Ubuntu 22.04 machine.

I just want to run an example-code to test if everything works:

```
from OCC.Display.SimpleGui import init_display

from OCC.Core.BRepPrimAPI import BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox

display, start_display, add_menu, add_function_to_menu = init_display()

my_box = BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox(10., 20., 30.).Shape()

display.DisplayShape(my_box, update=True)

start_display()
```

I had an error message that there is no visualization backend (or something similar, sadly I don't remember the exact wording). Because of that and the fact that I read about similar topics before, I installed pySide2 via conda inside the venv (`conda install -c conda-forge pyside2`). After that the error while executing the code changed to:

```
qt - pyside2 backend - Qt version ..
qt-qpa-plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in ""
###### 3D rendering pipe initialisation #####
Display3d class initialization starting ...
Aspect_DisplayConnection created.
OpenGL_GraphicDriver created.
V3d_Viewer created.
AIS_InteractiveContext created.
V3d View created
```

I tried installing the following things to solve the problem:

```
# wxpython
sudo apt update

sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev

sudo pip install wxpython # dauert seeeehr lange

# pyqt
conda install pyqt

# qtwayland5
sudo apt install qtwayland5

export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland
```

But nothing worked till now. Only the `pyside2` before the `backend` changed to `pyqt5`. I would love to hear your thoughts regarding this topic and if someone stumbled upon this error before.

See also the same question of mine on this opencascade post: https://dev.opencascade.org/content/missing-qt-platform-plugin-wayland-pyside-pyqt-visualization